# Pop queued item into sns after ttl expires

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I would like to achieve following architecture using SQS and SNS:

1. Push message into SQS queue with a delay
2. Notify all subscribers using SNS once the message delay(ttl) has expired

I know how to do first (practical) part, but not sure how to integrate SQS with SNS. Or maybe some other architecture should be applied in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

While you can push a message onto an SQS Delay Queue (with delay up to 15 minutes) you would still need an application to pull the message off the queue and publish it to your SNS topic. There's no feature built into SQS/SNS to do this**, as far as I know. Or you could simply hold onto the message and then, after a period of time, publish it directly to the SNS topic but then you would not benefit from the durability of SQS.

** Note that there is a fanout feature where you can publish to an SNS topic and subscribe multiple SQS queues to that topic so that each subscribed queue receives a copy of the message for independent processing. Not your case, but worth knowing about anyway.

It might be worth expanding on what you are trying to build here in case other design patterns are appropriate.

Comment: I basically want to clone functionality of basic delayed message queue. 
Let's say master server is pushing 3 different messages with intervals of 10, 15, 30 mins and slave server have to consume this messages on expiry.
I would like to avoid polling slave each 5, 15, 30 mins but receive those messages automatically using a webhook.